# Parsing spaces into html header

Tags: php, http

I am trying to google a solution for parsing a PHP variable "Joe Soap"
into a html header
I am expecting:
http://myurl.com&name=joe soap
but I am getting
http://myurl.com&name=joe

I know I can not have spaces in my http header but I can't find out how to parse my variable.
I just need a hint so that I can google it.
Regards

Answer (score 2):

Without some code it's guessing work.

I think you need PHP `urlencode`

```
$test = 'Joe Soap';
echo 'http://example.com/?name=' . urlencode ( $test );
```

Which results in: `http://example.com/?name=Joe+Soap`

Answer (score 0):

2 minutes after I ask the question,   I find the answer.
use the urlencode function in php
regards